# Google Sheets CSV download does not work with different data types in column

Tags: google-sheets, export-to-csv

**NOTE:** workaround is included. I thought it should be documented for the next person.

### Background:

I have a pretty simple table in a Google Sheets document.

| id | start#0.key | start#0.value | start#1.key | start#1.value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | HelpLookup | 2002 | TitleLookup | H.D.1 |
| Beta | Colour | Red | Background | 2003 |

---

I am exporting the contents of the sheet via the download url:
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{documentId}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv`

Here is a copy of the raw text bytes downloaded from that url:

```
"id","start#0.key","start#0.value","start#1.key","start#1.value"
"Alpha","HelpLookup","2002","TitleLookup",""
"Beta","Colour","","Background","2003"
```

---

### Issue:

**Notice:**

- the **'start#1.value'** cell for the second row (Alpha) is an empty string, not **'H.D.1'**.
- the **'start#0.value'** cell for the third row (Beta) is an empty string, not **'Red'**.

It appears that because the **'Beta'** value for this cell is a Number and the Formatting for the column is **'Automatic'** any string values are being removed during the export.
[image: screenshot of Google Sheets UI showing the "Format | Number" menu option indicating "Automatic"]

### Resolution (not ideal)

When I change the columns' Format to "Number | Plain Text" I am able to get all the data from the CSV export.
[image: screenshot of Google Sheets UI showing the "Format | Number" menu option indicating "Plain text"]

Here is the url-downloaded data:

```
"id","start#0.key","start#0.value","start#1.key","start#1.value"
"Alpha","HelpLookup","2002","TitleLookup","H.D.1"
"Beta","Colour","Red","Background","2003"
```

No other changes were made to the Google Sheets document - only changing the format of the **'start#1.value'** column to "Number - Plain text".

### Expectation:

Seeing as I am explicitly asking for **'csv'** output, see the **'tqx=out:csv'** in the url's query string parameters, that I would get all the text from my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same experience as you. In that case, I could retrieve the correct CSV data by changing the endpoint.

From the situation that you can export the Spreadsheet as the CSV using `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{documentId}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv`, I thought that your Spreadsheet is publicly shared. If my understanding is correct, how about changing the endpoint as follows?

#### From:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{documentId}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv
```

#### To:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/export?format=csv
```

Or, if you want to retrieve the specific sheet, please use `gid` as follows.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/export?format=csv&gid={sheetId}
```

Comment: It looks like you can (only?) find the gid by looking at the URL when you are on that tab in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tanaike. Now I can go an see if the rest of the code can "deal with" the missing "'s :)

The format of the export is slightly different that the 'gviz' version. It doesn't have the "'s around all the fields.
I was curious about 'spaces' or 'commas' in the fields so I did a small test.

```
id,start#0.key,start#0.value,start#1.key,start#1.value
Alpha,HelpLookup,2002,"Title,Lookup",H.D.1
Beta,Colour,Red,Back ground,2003
```

I have changed 'TitleLookup' string, for Alpha, to include a comma. Then the 'Background' key, for Beta, to include a space to see what happens.